# Can't pull images from gcr.io using kubeadm

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, kubeadm

I cannot pull images from gcr.io using kubeadm. I do not understand the problem, as it seems to have correct internet access to get the latest version info correctly.

This is running on a ubuntu 20.04 machine. Kubernetes has been installed with:

```
  curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add - && \
  echo "deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list && \
  sudo apt-get update -q && \
  sudo apt-get install -qy kubelet=1.19.15-00 kubectl=1.19.15-00 kubeadm=1.19.15-00

  sudo kubeadm init

  kubectl apply -f "https://cloud.weave.works/k8s/net?k8s-version=$(kubectl version | base64 | tr -d '\n')"
  kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
```

But running kubeadm as preflight image pull returns with this error

```
kubeadm config images pull --v=5
I1021 08:14:07.979301 1611622 initconfiguration.go:104] detected and using CRI socket: /var/run/dockershim.sock
I1021 08:14:07.979712 1611622 interface.go:400] Looking for default routes with IPv4 addresses
I1021 08:14:07.979726 1611622 interface.go:405] Default route transits interface "eth0"
I1021 08:14:07.980302 1611622 interface.go:208] Interface eth0 is up
I1021 08:14:07.980394 1611622 interface.go:256] Interface "eth0" has 3 addresses :[45.142.179.100/22 2a03:4000:4a:e35:4490:e9ff:feca:f24f/64 fe80::4490:e9ff:feca:f24f/64].
I1021 08:14:07.980421 1611622 interface.go:223] Checking addr  45.142.179.100/22.
I1021 08:14:07.980436 1611622 interface.go:230] IP found 45.142.179.100
I1021 08:14:07.980448 1611622 interface.go:262] Found valid IPv4 address 45.142.179.100 for interface "eth0".
I1021 08:14:07.980458 1611622 interface.go:411] Found active IP 45.142.179.100 
I1021 08:14:08.074551 1611622 version.go:185] fetching Kubernetes version from URL: https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable-1.txt
I1021 08:14:13.375386 1611622 version.go:254] remote version is much newer: v1.22.2; falling back to: stable-1.20
I1021 08:14:13.375442 1611622 version.go:185] fetching Kubernetes version from URL: https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable-1.20.txt
exit status 1
output: Error response from daemon: Get "https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup k8s.gcr.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
, error
```

*Update*

I'm just using a blank ubuntu machine, add a new user:

```
$ sudo adduser <USER>
$ sudo usermod -aG sudo <USER>
$ exit
$ ssh <USER>@<IP>
$ sudo visudo

<USER> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

$ sudo passwd -l root
```

and run this routine. That's all I do before installing kubernetes as shown above.

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository \
"deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
$(lsb_release -cs) \
stable"

sudo touch /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y update > /dev/null
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -yq \
  apache2-utils \
  apt-transport-https \
  build-essential \
  ca-certificates \
  cifs-utils \
  curl \
  containerd.io \
  docker-ce \
  docker-ce-cli \
  gnupg2 \
  haveged \
  libpam-pwdfile \
  nfs-common \
  nfs-kernel-server \
  python \
  software-properties-common \
  unattended-upgrades \
  vsftpd > /dev/null

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"],
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "100m"
  },
  "storage-driver": "overlay2"
}
EOF
sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker
sudo systemctl enable docker.service
swapoff -a
sudo exportfs -a

sudo usermod -aG docker <USER>
sudo hostnamectl set-hostname kubernetes-main
```

Comment: Could you try `curl -v https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable-1.20.txt` and check if it gives you 302 response?

Comment: @kupson Running this on the server returns a 302 response

Comment: I'd bet you are using a proxy, and your user (plus maybe root as well) have configured proxy settings that either (a) kubelet does not use (b) that `output:` is coming from an entirely separate Node. Either way, you'll have to provide more details in order for anyone to help you, because that error could be caused by any number of things

Comment: @mdaniel I do not use a proxy. I added my install routine to the post. I don't see the problem with the created user...

Comment: It seems that you mixed some different configurations. Previously you install `kubeadm=1.19.15-00,` but then in logs: `falling back to: stable-1.20`
Did you use any manual for kubernetes installation? Where you deployed Ubuntu - physical server, VM, etc.?

Comment: @AndrewSkorkin That's how I upgrade from 1.19.15 to 1.20 (https://v1-20.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-upgrade/)

Comment: Sorry @user3142695, but I don't understand. Are you trying to install or update Kubernetes, since "I'm just using a blank ubuntu machine"?

Comment: Hello @user3142695. Any updates?

Comment: @user3142695 Has your issue been resolved? If yes, can you post the procedure you've followed as a solution and accept it?